# Change the size of all images contained in a div

Tags: html, css

Let `<div id='blah'>` contain many images. Is there an easy way to set the size of all the `<div>`'s children-images to half (or 30% or anything else)  of their original sizes? *(if possible, without having to loop on all children-images with JS)*

```
<div id='blah'>
<img src="http://www.locanto.info/petites_annonces/images/dog.png"></img>
<img src="http://www.alsacroc.fr/contents/img/chiot.jpg"></img>
<img src="http://static.wamiz.fr/images/animaux/chiens/large/chien-du-groenland.jpg"></img>
</div>
```

[Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/y4appovh/1/)

Comment: If you're trying to resize them according to their original size, then you will have to use javascript, loop through them each, and set accordingly. Why wouldn't you want to do it that way?

Comment: half of its width or height?

Comment: @NickDugger : because I will have dynamic content with sometimes new <img> arriving, and some other disappearing, etc.   so if I could avoid to test if a new <img> has arrived in order to resize it, and to have a "global"  resize that would work for all images-children of the div, this would have been great!

Comment: Well, as I said, if you're resizing according to its original dimensions, you need to do it via JS, and then recall the function when a new image lands, or set new dimensions to the new image before it even hits the DOM

Answer (score 2):

You'd need to use `transform` and `scale`, which work relative to the original size of the element:

```
#blah img {
    transform: scale(0.3);
}
```

Remember [transform's browser prefixes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform#Browser_compatibility).

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/y4appovh/4/)

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can use css:

```
div#blah img {
     width:30%;
     height:auto;
}
```

or you can use zoom (0 to 1) to resize the image without relating to parent div.

ZOOM cross browser:

```
-moz-transform: scale(0.5); /* Firefox */
-moz-transform-origin: 0 0;

-o-transform: scale(0.5); /* Opera */
-o-transform-origin: 0 0;

-webkit-transform: scale(0.5); /* Safari And Chrome */
-webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;

transform: scale(0.5); /* Standard Property */
transform-origin: 0 0;  /* Standard Property */
```

Comment: No, if you compare original JSfiddle to yours, you'll see the biggest image's size has changed a lot, whereas the little image's size has changed only a little... I would like proportional size-change  : all images should have 30% of their original sizes.

Comment: so, you have to use zoom: (0 to 1). This value will resize image proportionally to its size.

Comment: do you mean the `zoom` property? It is not supported on Firefox

Comment: there are many zoom propriety for every browser. Look at the answer.